# Apply CSS for AMX commandButton

Tags: jquery, css, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

I am new in Oracle MAF. I have two commandButtons. While clicking button I want to change the whole body background color. How can I do this in AMX page. to write button onClick function in AMX page.

```js
<amx:commandButton text="Red" id="red" styleClass="blue-background"/>
```

```js
$("#red").onclick(function(){
   
   $("#pp1").css("background-color","yellow");
    
});
```

Here I have written AMX Page commandButton Code and jQuery code. How can I call The AMX commandButton ID inside the jQuery. The functionality is not working.

Comment: Please write if there is any error displayed inside the console.

Comment: No Error. I dont know how to call that commandButton id in javascript. I have written same "id" in onclick function. But its not affecting.

Comment: My requirement, While clicking that commandButton, I want to change the body background color. In above code, "pp1" is my body id.

Comment: First of all you have to add the javaScript into your feature in feature.xml.
then call a js function containing the code to change the background color from your bean class

Comment: is it compulsory to use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

### Step1

Create a .js file and add it to your feature.

### Step2

in that .js file write a function

```
bgColorChange = function(){
  // your jQuery code
}
```

### Step3

from your bean class invoke the js function

```
AdfmfContainerUtilities.invokeContainerJavaScriptFunction(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getFeatureId(), "bgColorChange",new Object[]{});
```

Try this and let me know if you are facing any issues